# EE 3.3.4 Search Module Not Installed

Tags: ee3

I continue to get a search path error when using Simple Search. Yes, I have a search/results template, and I have tried hard coding the search/results path into Simple Search.

I've checked the Add-On Manager and I do not see that the Search Module is installed. I can't tell from the documentation whether this module is something that would be displayed in the Add-On Manager, although I would imagine it would be.

Basically two problems:

1. Search path error when using Simple Search
2. No evidence the Search module is properly installed

These things suggest the module is not properly installed. Can someone yield some insight?

Comment: In the current versions of EE you won't find the Simple Search module in the Add On Manager, it's installed by default.  Can you post your code so that it's easier to diagnose your issue?

Comment: Good to know. This forum doesn't permit me to show the code BUT it is standard cut and paste right out of the User Guide.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping I understand the problem correctly. Can you try something similar to...

```
{exp:search:simple_form channel="subpage" search_in="everywhere"  results="10" result_page="sandbox/search-results" no_result_page="sandbox/no-results"}
     <input type="search" name="keywords" placeholder="Enter search words">
     <button class="submit search">Search</button>
{/exp:search:simple_form}
```

Where "sandbox" is the group and "search-results" is the template.  Make sure everything is spelled correctly as I've seen this be a problem before.  Also double check the template manager to make sure EE is properly adding your groups/templates.